# Python string formatting and padding

Tags: python, command, padding, floating, f-string

I was wondering if there is a way in Python > 3.6, using f-strings, to achieve the following: I have a number `2451545.00000` which I would like to print as `%.5f` but at the same time I'd like to have it centre justified e.g. using f-string `{' '}^{20}`. Is there a way to achieve that in a single command e.g., `{2451545.00000:.5{' '}^{20}}` or something like that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `^` in the f-string:

```py
num = 2451545.00000
print(repr(f"{num:^20.5f}")) # '   2451545.00000    '
```

You can read the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) for relevant information. The `^` is listed as an "align" option.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're going for can be written as follows:

```
my_number = 2451545.00000000
my_string = f"{my_number:^20.5f}"
print(my_string)
```

Hope it helps.